# TikZ:How to connect nodes in another way

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have this...

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes.geometric,decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.shapes,decorations.markings,patterns,calc,fit,arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex',auto,inner sep=2mm,node distance=2cm and 3cm,scale=1]

%set styles for the axis between turbine and pump and for the boxes

\tikzset{box1/.style={draw,minimum width=2.5cm,rectangle,thick}}
\tikzset{deco/.style={decoration={markings,
                       mark=at position #1 with {\arrow{>}}},
                       postaction={decorate}}}
\tikzset{turb/.style={draw,trapezium,shape border rotate=90,inner sep=1pt,minimum width=2.5cm,trapezium stretches=true,trapezium angle=80,on grid}}   

% draw nodes
\node[turb] (turbine) {Turbine};
\node[box1,on grid,below left=of turbine] (condenser){Condenser};
%connections
\begin{scope}[>=triangle 45]
 \draw [deco=0.6]  (turbine.bottom left corner) |- (condenser);
 \end{scope}
%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But i need this way...new pink connection

[image]

> Is it possible to connect near the end (Red line). say 1 or 2 mm away from
>   turbine.bottom left corner...

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`($(turbine)!.5!(condenser)$)` calculates the middle (`0.5`) between `turbine` and `condenser`.

`turbine.south` is equivalent to `turbine.-90` (-90 is an angle) and `condenser.east` is equivalent to `condenser.0`.

So, here, two others possibilities:

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{%
  positioning,shapes.geometric,decorations.pathmorphing,%
  decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.shapes,%
  decorations.markings,patterns,calc,fit,arrows,%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}%
  [>=latex',auto,inner sep=2mm,node distance=2cm and 3cm,scale=1]

  % set styles for the axis between turbine and pump and for the boxes

  \tikzset{box1/.style={draw,minimum width=2.5cm,rectangle,thick}}
  \tikzset{
    deco/.style={%
      decoration={%
        markings,
        mark=at position #1 with {\arrow{>}}
      },
      postaction={decorate},
    },
    turb/.style={%
      draw,trapezium,shape border rotate=90,
      inner sep=1pt,minimum width=2.5cm,
      trapezium stretches=true,trapezium angle=80,on grid,
    }
  }   

  % draw nodes
  \node[turb] (turbine) {Turbine};
  \node[box1,on grid,below left=of turbine] (condenser){Condenser};
  % connections
  \begin{scope}[>=triangle 45]

    \draw [deco=0.5,red] (turbine.south)
    |- ($(turbine.south)!.5!(condenser.north)$)
    -| (condenser.north);

    \draw [deco=0.5,violet] (turbine.-70) |- (condenser.10);
  \end{scope}
%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Adding

```
\draw [deco=0.7,pink] (turbine.south) |- ++(-1,-0.2) -| (condenser);
```

to the last scope is sufficient.

[image]

Comment: A variant (without absolute coordinate) uses: \draw [deco=0.5,red] (turbine) |- ($(turbine)!.5!(condenser)$) -| (condenser);

Comment: Very fine idea, with `($(turbine)!.5!(condenser)$)` it's very easy to adjust the connection. Another possibility is `(turbine.south) --++(0,-1em) -| (condenser); `.

Comment: @PolGab: THis also works well...Thank you.  But ($(turbine)!.5!(condenser)$) is calc operation. i do not know the meaning...

Comment: Can we use like numerical values like (0,-1em) instead of (turbine.south)

Comment: You can use angle arguments such as `\draw [deco=0.7,pink] (turbine.-70) |- (condenser.north east);` for your edited question.